Is it possible to translate interjections like "argh" and "gah" into German?
I am translating the text of a video game from English into German which has numerous terms which I am not sure how or if I can translate. Some of them could be called onomatopoeia. For example:

Aagh, argh, ragh and gah (expressions of rage or pain)
Bah (expression of contempt or disgust from a haughty character)
Whee (expression of exhilaration)
Ooh (a character is excitedly anticipating taking revenge)
Zzz (snoring sound)


I'll give it a shot:

Aagh, argh, ragh and gah (expressions of rage or pain)

Grrr for rage, Autsch for pain

Bah (expression of contempt or disgust from a haughty character)

Pah

Whee (expression of exhilaration)

Hui (if connected to a motion) or Juhu (if not)

Ooh (a character is excitedly anticipating taking revenge)

Haha (with stress on the second syllable)

Zzz (snoring sound)

Chr

Args is also common for anger, similar to argh.

A quick note for English speakers: "chr(rr)" when pronounced with a German "ch" and a German "r" sounds much more like actual snoring than English "zzz".


Is it possible to translate interjections

That depends on what you mean by "translate". Of course, German has - like perhaps any other language - similar interjections because the need of people to express the feeling of rage, pain, exhilaration and what else feelings you mentioned is the same everywhere.
The following effort is, of course, no "translation" in the classical sense and consulting a dictionary might provide different or no results at all. Also, it could perhaps be possible to "fine-tune" it given more context. So, take the list cum grano salis:

Aagh, argh, ragh and gah (expressions of rage or pain)
Au!, Aua! (pain only)
Ahhh! (could work for rage)

Bah (expression of contempt or disgust from a haughty character)
Pff!

Whee (expression of exhilaration)
Ja! Oh ja!

Ooh (a character is excitedly anticipating taking revenge)
maybe: hmmm!

Zzz (snoring sound)
Chhh! Chrrrr!


